# Order results of a query by values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function to populate an ajax calendar with events. 
I'm querying a date (format Ymd) from custom field in my wordpress database.

```
        $metakey2 = 'jour';
        $jours = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey2) );
        if ($jours) {
            $years = substr($jours, 0, 4); // OUTPUT YEAR FROM DATE
            $months = substr($jours, 5, 2);  // OUTPUT MONTH FROM DATE
            $days = substr($jours, 7, 2); // OUTPUT DAY FROM DATE

                foreach $years as $year {
                    foreach $months as $month {

                        if ($y == $year AND $m == $month) {
                            $events = array(
                                foreach $days as $day {
                                    $day => array(
                                        0 => array(
                                            "0" => "Lorem ipsum dolor 111", 
                                        )
                                    );
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }   
        }

    `
```

I'm definitely no expert and I've been trying to make this work for hours now... Can someone point me towards the right direction please?
Thank you,
Manue

Comment: Do you use custom_post? What type of post do you query to get post_meta?

Could u explain how it works ?

Comment: I use products from woocommerce with custom fields. For each product I have a date entered in a custom field. What I need is to output those products in a calendar, hence the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$metakey2 = 'jour';
$jours = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey2) );

// Chaeck the data returned isn't null, blank, 0-length array, etc.
if (!empty($jours)) {
    // Initialize events array
    $events = array();

    // Loop through the data
    foreach ($jours as $jour) {
        $year  = substr($jour, 0, 4); // OUTPUT YEAR FROM DATE
        $month = substr($jour, 5, 2); // OUTPUT MONTH FROM DATE
        $day   = substr($jour, 7, 2); // OUTPUT DAY FROM DATE

        // PROCESS YOUR DATA HERE
        ...
    }
}
```

The key is the foreach loop after the empty check. You need to loop through the data that is returned from the db as an array.